# How can i detect the places when the red line starting to move over/above the black line?

Tags: c#, graph, plot

Or how can i detect when the red line is starting to make acsent/slope/climb up ?

I have this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < averagesOriginal.Count - 69; i++)
            {
                int y = i + 35;
                if (averagesOriginal[y] <= resultings[i])
                {
                    if (averagesOriginal[y] >= resultings[i])
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show("above");
                    }
                }
            }
```

The averagesOriginal List present the Red line in the graph and the resultings List present the Black line.
I need to find the places where the Red line is starting to climb above the black line.
I attached an image of the graph showing the red line and the black line and i marked in black cicules the places i think that should be where it start.

The left two siccules i think should be where the red line start to climb up above the black line.

I need to find the indexs(and the numers in each index) of the the places all over the graph where it start to climb the red over the black.

I dont need all the Red above the black only the place/s where it start.

It should be two index.

The conditions should be: the first index is where the Red under the black then on the next one single index forward it should be above the black.

If you look at the graph in the beginning the red is all the time under the black. 
I need to find somehow where the red is under the black and in the nexto ne single index the red is above the black. This meaning the red start to climb.

So how can i do it according to my code ?

( In the image attached the left two black cicrucles i drawed show the first red index under the black then the next red index is above the black. This is the places i should search for.

[image]

Comment: i'm very sleepy right now, but i think that the inner if statement's got no business being inside the outer if.

Comment: From the image it looks like the red climbs over the black one at 150, 161, and 170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a flag keeping track of where the line currently is and flip the flag as it passes.

```
bool isRedBelow = averagesOriginal[0] < resultings[0];

for (int i = 0; i < averagesOriginal.Count - 69; i++)
{
    int y = i + 35;

    if (isRedBelow && averagesOriginal[y] > resultings[i])
    {
        isRedBelow = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Red is now above");
    }
    else if (!isRedBelow && averagesOriginal[y] < resultings[i])
    {
        isRedBelow = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Red is now below");
    }
}
```

As the line crosses, the flag flips. This allows you to continue grabbing each flip no matter how many there are.

I purposely didn't handle the `equal` cases (`>=` or `<=`) because I wasn't too sure what you wanted; it might be a safe assumption that if they're equal, it's because it's in the process of crossing over, but I'm not sure if you'll get a case where they're equal but the red line reverses course at that moment. I'll leave that to you.

Also, in the initial `isRedBelow` assignment, I didn't check if the arrays had `Length > 0`, but I'm guessing that's not an issue (if it is, you can fix it)

If managing the `false/true` states of `isRedBelow` gets confusing, feel free to replace it with an enum, perhaps something like:

```
enum RedLinePosition
{
    BelowBlack,
    AboveBlack,
    EqualToBlack //if necessary
}
```

EDIT: I'm not too sure what's going on with the `- 69` in the `for` loop, or the `int y = i + 35` offset; I'm guessing those are outside the bounds of the question. But I'm assuming the offsets are there to compensate for `averagesOriginal` and `resultings` not having their elements lined up. If `averagesOriginal[N]` and `resultings[N]` are supposed to represent the `Y` coordinate on the graph for both lines at the point `X = N`, then I suggest you fix your looping indices there so that they match.